# What do these small numbers like powers but are below mean?

Tags: soft-question

I have encountered those small numbers that are like exponents but are beneath numbers instead of above. What do they Mean?

$$x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$$

Comment: Such *subscripts* just distinguish values.  $x_1$ has some value, $x_2$ has some value.  You could instead use $a$, $b$, $c$, but that gets ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are indices to distinguish the variables $x_i$ with $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

They are often used for example in multivariable calculus and linear algebra when we deal with more than $2$ or $3$ variables as an alternative to $x$, $y$, $z$, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the simple And straightforward Answer!!

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other good answers, sometimes "$x$" denotes a vector in $n$-dimensional space, and "$x_i$" is the $i$-th component of it, written as an $n$-tuple: $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n)$.

Also, sometimes $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ is a sequence of *values* that a variable $x$ can take.

Sometimes, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are names for the two solutions to a quadratic equation in the "variable" $x$...

Basically, though, unlike superscripts (=exponents), subscripts mostly do *not* denote any standard operation on the variable to which they're attached. In the vector case, this *is* so, if we want to interpret it that way... but, still, not really.

Answer (score 1):

Each of them is called an **index** (plural: indices) or, rarely, *subscript*. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_notation